# How to offset 3D transformation matrix?

Tags: opengl, glsl, webgl, affinetransform

The context of the issue here is that I'm working on a 3D project that is using separate tools for Mesh data and Animation data exports. These tools have different origin points.

- Meshes are exported with 0,0,0 as the lower left aligned point of the mesh AABB.
- Animations are centered on x,z and bottom aligned on y.

I've recently introduced a physics engine which uses a separate, fully centered 0,0,0 rigid body space.

I'm using the physics engine as the source of truth and trying to translate the different origin points accordingly.

My current vert position calculation looks like:

```
  gl_Position = projection * view * model * joint * (centerOffset * vec4(position.xyz, 1));
```

I have a series of transformation matrices being applied to 3D verts.

- `position.xyz`

  is the original vert positions
- `centerOffset`

  is a translation transformation that offsets the verts to their respective position in a 0,0,0 centered AABB.
- `joint`

  is a transformation matrix from a Blender exported joint animation.
- `model`

  is the world position and rotation matrix

The problem I'm encountering with this approach is that the verts are now centered around the `model` world position correctly, But when a joint animation is applied it is distorted because the animation `joint` matrices are offset from +Y and the mesh data is centered on Y:0

What I would expect to do here is offset the `joint` matrix so they are in the correct Y range of the 0,0,0 centered verts.

I have tried multiplying the `joint` matrix by a Y-offset translation matrix but it ends up shifting the entire distorted set of verts by the new offset and not the specific joint transformation.

I essentially need the equivalent operation to: going into Blender and manually moving all the joints down the Y axis so they are Y centered and not bottom aligned and then reexporting the joint matrices

Comment: Usually your joint matrix is the result of a transform hierarchy that has its origin transform matrix at the base(often called the "root" node), that's where you'd apply the pivot transformation.

Comment: I would think you need to apply that offset to the inverseBindMatrix of each joint

Comment: wow thanks @gman I do have copies of the inverseBindMatrices I will give that a try.